# IntelliJ syntax highlighting for jinja files (.jinja, .j2)

Tags: intellij-idea, jinja2

Question is pretty much in the title. Does IntelliJ have native syntax highlighting for `.jinja` and `.j2` files?

If not is there a plugin?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7792-yaml-ansible-support offers *some* support for `jinja` files.

To ensure that this plugin is associated with `jinja` files:

- Go to `File > Preferences > Editor > File Types`
- Under `Recognized File Types` scroll down to `YAML/Ansible` and select it
- Under `Registered Patterns` click the `+` icon and enter `*.jinja`.

  [image]

With this configuration in place your `jinja` files will open into this plugin. If they do not, then `jinja files` must be already associated with one of the other `Recognized File Types` in which case you'll need to scroll through them to find the culprit and remove `*.jinja` from its `Registered Patterns`.

Comment: I've installed that plugin, disabled the default YAML plugin, but I still don't have syntax highlighting for *.jinja files. Is there anything else I have to do?

Comment: I've updated the answer to describe how to associate `jinja` files with this plugin.

Comment: Thanks! I've noticed that after doing this, jinja statements, expressions, and macros are still not highlighted. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: I think you're now coming up against the limits of that plugin :(

Comment: This plugin doesn't add syntax highlights for Jinja2 templates (.jinja, .j2), only "Reference Jinja2 variable declaration" in Ansible YAML files.

Comment: I had no "YAML/Ansible" option but just "YAML"

Comment: Note/tip for WebStorm users: I've managed to get pretty good results for `*.jinja` files by using `Twig` plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7303-twig and registering `*.jinja` / `*.jinja2` extensions just as above, but under `File > Preferences > Editor > File Types > Twig` section

Answer (score 24):

Try the [**Python**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/plugin-overview.html) plugin with IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, that has support for Jinja2 [Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/templates.html).

Comment: I can only imagine this had no votes because most people aren't using Ultimate Edition. If you are, this is definitely the best way to get Jinja2 support.

Comment: I have the Python plugin installed on my IntelliJ Ultimate but I still don't see any syntax highlighting for jinja files

Comment: Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Python Template Languages -> Jinja2

Comment: Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Python Template Languages -> Jinja2 had no effect on my side either :(

Comment: Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Python Template Languages -> Jinja2: Add the file type you want Jinja2 to template. In my case we are working with .js files so I added the filetype to the list of files.
 My employer pays for my Ultimate edition and it's a great tool, but way too expensive for me if to pay for it myself.

Comment: You may also have to associate the .jinja association with Jinja 2 templates, since it only has .jinja2 out of the box.

Comment: Settings -> Editor -> File Types in Recognized File Types find Jinja 2 template then on the right click + on file name patterns and add *.j2

Answer (score 15):

With recent version of Intellij, you don't need any plugin any more.

- Go to <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Editor</kbd> > <kbd>File Types</kbd>
- Under `Recognized Files Types`, choose **Jinja 2 Template**
- Under `File Name Patterns` add `*.j2` for jinja2, and/or `*.jinja` for jinja

For Ansible yaml jinja 2 templates:

- Under `Recognized Files Types`, choose **YAML/Ansible**
- Under `File Name Patterns` add `*.yaml.j2` and `*yml.j2`

Comment: Excellent post :)

Comment: I don't have both "Jinja 2 Template"/"YAML/Ansible" in the list of types

Comment: Hi @chillappreciator I also didn't have it, so I simply added it with the plus sign to the list of Recognized file types and associated with *.json.j2. You can even configure block comments and keywords manually in that screen. Not perfect, but better than what I had before.

Answer (score 6):

Just for sanity sake. I found my solution in a combination of both answers previously posted.

Besides the [Python](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/plugin-overview.html) plugin as @Andrei states it is needed that the file extension is recognized as explained above by @glytching: `File > Preferences > Editor > File Types`, for me the pattern `*.j2` was missing.

As a good thing to do also would be to mark the directory as `Template` as described in section *To define template directories* on the referenced [templates link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/templates.html) given by @Andrei:

```
1. In the Settings/Preferences dialog, click the Project Structure page.

2. Choose the directory to be marked as a template root.

3. Do one of the following:

  * Click Templates on the toolbar of the Content roots pane.

  * Choose Templates on the directory's context menu.
```